# How to move a row according to several conditions in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

First thank you for your time. I am working on a google sheet and I would like to check for every row the value in one column for example the F1, F2, F3, F4 ... !

If the value is 1 for one of the row then I want to move my row to another sheet. But I need my macro to check each row (always the same column). The cells of column F are a formula of several conditions. If all the conditions are right I got

I find a way to check for one specific cell but I want to check for all of them "one by one".

````
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
        var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
        var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

        var cell = sheet1.getRange("F12").getCell(1, 1);// Here my problem is the fact that I am checking only F12 and I want to check each row.

        var rowtoInsert = sheet2.getLastRow(); // To put copy paste my row from Sheet 1 to the last row of Sheet 2

        if(cell.getValue() == "compareString") //compare cell.getValue() =="1"   {

        sheet2.insertRows(rowtoInsert); //Insert a empty row in sheet2    

        var range2 = sheet2.getRange(rowtoInsert,1,1,sheet1.getLastColumn()); // Select sheet2 row as a range

       sheet1.getRange(cell.getRow(),1, 1,sheet1.getLastColumn()).copyTo(range2); // copy the selected sheet1 range into sheet2 range

     sheet1.deleteRow(cell.getRow()); //delete the row in sheet1  } }```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Looking through previous questions and answers, or reading through the documentation will be the quickest way to understand what you need to do here; see especially [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) and [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) from Google's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome on SO. There is indeed a lot of content you can find here and in the documentation, as suggested by @sinaraheneba. A good example can however help to get started, so hopefully this is one. I commented it as much as I could so you can get the reasoning, feel free to ask questions if you have any, or report issues if you find some.

```
function moveRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

  /* In order to manipulate bigger sets of data, best to get all content once in an two-dimensions array
   * and then work on that array. 
   * In your case, I'd just with 3 arrays: one for Sheet1 values, one for Sheet1 formulas, and one that you will append to Sheet2.
   * Arrays for Sheet1 will contain all data from Sheet1, and you'll "just" remove lines that need to be transfered to Sheet2
   * */

  var Sheet1Data = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var Sheet1Formulas = sheet1.getDataRange().getFormulas();
  var Sheet2Data = [];

  /* Start looping through all the rows in Sheet1 to check the value for the sixth ("F") column. 
   * Remember, in JS / App Scripts, array indexes start at 0, while in Google Sheet, rows and column indexes start at 1, which can be confusing
   * Since I have a header row in Sheet1, I'll start my loop at row 1 (row 0 being the headers) so I don't move the headers away and spend time checking them
   * */

  for (var row = 1 ; row < Sheet1Data.length ; row++) { // So I'll check all rows of Sheet1 ; getDataRange() above stops at the last row and last column with actual content

    for (var col = 0 ; col < Sheet1Data[row].length ; col++){ // For all columns in that row, if a formula exists, we'll replace the value with the actual formul
      if (Sheet1Formulas[row][col]) Sheet1Data[row][col] = Sheet1Formulas[row][col];
    }

    if (Sheet1Data[row][5] == 1) { // Checking if my sixth column ("F", inded 5 in JS) is equal to 1
      Sheet2Data.push(Sheet1Data[row]); // Adding the whole row to the data that will need to go to Sheet2
      Sheet1Data.splice(row, 1); // Removing the row in the data for sheet 1
      Sheet1Formulas.splice(row, 1); // Removing the row in the formulas for sheet 1 to keep them in sync
      row--; // Since we removed one line, we need to make sure we also adjust the index counter, otherwise we'll skip lines
    }
  }

  /* Now our two variables do contain the content that is expected to go in each sheet.  
   * For Sheet1, we'll replace the entire content with the new one, so it's quite straightforward.
   * For Sheet2, we'll append the content to the existing one, assuming that the operation can be repeated, and thus that we can't loose what we have there already
   * */ 

  sheet1.clearContents().getRange(1,1,Sheet1Data.length, Sheet1Data[0].length).setValues(Sheet1Data);
  // clearContents() removes the current data, but keeps formatting
  // getRange() selects a range that has the same size as the data we want to input. Remember the subtelty of indexes starting at 1 instead of 0 here
  // setValues() writes the content of our array in the cells

  if (Sheet2Data.length > 0) sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, Sheet2Data.length, Sheet2Data[0].length).setValues(Sheet2Data);
  // same reasoning, but we don't clear, and we select a range that starts after the last row with content (getLastRow() + 1). 
  // we also only do this if there is actually content to be moved to Sheet2 (so if the Sheet2Data list is longer than 0 elements) to avoid errors

} // and we're done.
```

I strongly advise you to go and read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) of the methods I use (e.g. `getRange()`, `getDataRange()`, `getValues()`, `setValues()`,...) so you become familiar with them and what exactly they do.

If you're not familiar with JS arrays, you may also want to read the JS documentation about them ([this page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) and the next ones)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I will take a look. Do you think it's better to start with the methods (getrange) or with JS arrays ?

Comment: Depends on what you're planning to do next, but definitely if you have experience with neither, starting with App Script will be easier. JS arrays and other components will be useful for more advanced things. I'd just go through the ones you see in my code for now, and then go deeper based on your needs. There's a lot to read about here in SO too, for your next script.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! And a last question. When I use the script, my formula of the last row is deleted. There is a way to avoid that (even maybe not copy-paste the last column) ?

Comment: I adjusted the code to take formulas into account. There is no "clean" way (afaik) to do this, you have to get both the values and the formulas in two different arrays, and "merge" them (so, replace the value with the formula when one is found) by looping through the entire array. Makes the script a bit slower, especially if you have a long sheet. If that's the case, there might be cleaner ways that could be envisioned, I guess.

Comment: Thanks again. Just a question, for the last script (and same for the previous one) i got "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". I don't understand why because everything was working yesterday ... any idea ?